# DirectX 11 Minimum Texture Size

Tags: directx, directx-11, render-to-texture

I'm working on a volume rendering program using DirectX 11.

I render both to a window ( `HWND` ) and to a texture ( `ID3D11Texture2D` ).

While the rendering for the `HWND` always looks correct, my `ID3D11Texture2D` looks corrupt for render sizes smaller than 64x64:

[image]

I wonder whether there is a *minimum* size limit for textures in DirectX 11.

Unfortunately, I was only able to find information about the *maximum* texture size limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no minimum texture size; 1x1x1 is valid.

It looks to me like you've mapped the 3D texture and are extracting the data while ignoring the "RowPitch" returned. On textures that are sufficiently small (or of unusual dimensions) the address at which the next row of texels begins need not necessarily be contiguous after the previous row, but will instead begin "RowPitch" bytes after the last.

See [D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) for extensive examples of using rowPitch and slicePitch properly.

Comment: The maximum texture size in D3D11 though is 16k by 16k.